# getKeyDown key presses no longer working, worked before. Debug also not outputting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, keydown

```
// Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {

    Vector3 curPos = transform.position;

    // after mouse has been left clicked and user presses spacebar or up arrow keys to carry out animations.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            //defining targetPos as the mouse click position
            Vector3 targetPos = Input.mousePosition;
            //outputting to console target position
            Debug.Log("Mouse Position " + targetPos);

            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                //newPos is the position of where miffy is meant to go.
                newPos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0.1199974f, hit.point.z);
                //setting isMiffyMoving to true to carry out miffyMove() actions
                isMiffyMoving = true;
            }
            //if statements to detmine miffy's direction when shes moving and output to console.
            if (targetPos.x < curPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going left");
                left = true;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            else if (targetPos.x > curPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going right");
                left = false;
                isIdle = false;
            }

            if (targetPos.z < curPos.z)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going backward");
                forward = false;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            else if (targetPos.z > curPos.z)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going forward");
                forward = true;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            //setting isIdle to true is miffy is not moving
            if (isIdle)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is idle");
                isIdle = true;
            }

            ////when up arrow key has been pressed animation stored in SpinJump will play
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
               anim.Play("SpinJump");
                Debug.Log("Working");
            }

            ////if spacebar has been pressed animation stored in cheer with play

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                anim.Play("cheer");
                Debug.Log("Working");
            }

        }
```

This is my code, key key presses won't work and "working" output only works when its put outside the mouse key down.

I've tried putting the keypresses into their own method and calling them in the update after mouse 0 has been pressed.

It worked this way before I added a move method that moves the character to the mouse click

Comment: GetXXXDown returns true only on the frame it is detected. So for those two conditions to be true at the same time, you'd have to be very precise or have really slow FPS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ive removed the get key downs from the first get mouse click. they output to console that they are working, but their animations still do not play, they seem to play very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to remove the GetKeyDowns from the mouse click but still within update. i added isIdle = false. there were too many actions trying to happen at once causing the jitters.

```
//if up arrow is pressed  animation stored in Spin will play
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        //setting idle to false to ensure it will not execute while spin is executing.
        isIdle = false;

        //setting cheer to false to ensure it will not execute while spin is executing.
        cheer = false;

        //setting spin to true.
        spin = true;
        skip = false;

        // playing animation for miffy to spin.
        anim.Play("SpinJump", 0, 0f);

        //testing if input is working by outputting text "working" to console.
        Debug.Log("Working");
    }

    ////if space has been pressed animation stored in Cheer with play
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //setting idle to false to ensure it will not execute while cheer is executing.
        isIdle = false;

        //setting spin to false to ensure it will not execute while cheer is executing.
        spin = false;

        //setting cheer to true.
        cheer = true;
        skip = false;

        // playing animation for miffy to cheer.
        anim.Play("Cheer", 0, 0f);

        //testing if input is working by outputting text "working" to console.
        Debug.Log("Working");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change like this:

```
void Update()
{

    Vector3 curPos = transform.position;

    // after mouse has been left clicked and user presses spacebar or up arrow keys to carry out animations.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            //defining targetPos as the mouse click position
            Vector3 targetPos = Input.mousePosition;
            //outputting to console target position
            Debug.Log("Mouse Position " + targetPos);

            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                //newPos is the position of where miffy is meant to go.
                newPos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0.1199974f, hit.point.z);
                //setting isMiffyMoving to true to carry out miffyMove() actions
                isMiffyMoving = true;
            }
            //if statements to detmine miffy's direction when shes moving and output to console.
            if (targetPos.x < curPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going left");
                left = true;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            else if (targetPos.x > curPos.x)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going right");
                left = false;
                isIdle = false;
            }

            if (targetPos.z < curPos.z)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going backward");
                forward = false;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            else if (targetPos.z > curPos.z)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is going forward");
                forward = true;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            //setting isIdle to true is miffy is not moving
            if (isIdle)
            {
                Debug.Log("Miffy is idle");
                isIdle = true;
            }
        }

    }

    ////when up arrow key has been pressed animation stored in SpinJump will play
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        anim.Play("SpinJump");
        Debug.Log("Working");
    }

    ////if spacebar has been pressed animation stored in cheer with play

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.Play("cheer");
        Debug.Log("Working");
    }
}
```

Using this your code is working properly and you get exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks, but the animation still just jitters and does not actually play out full animation

Comment: What kind of thing is happening on it can you give the small video of it?

Answer (score 0):

it doesnot work because you have kept the condition for the space button inside the codition where you check for mouse button click.. that debug.log will give working output only if you are pressing mouse and then hit space at the same time without lifting the mouse click.

Comment: when i take away the first mouse click condition it outputs working but the animation does not play, just jitters.

Comment: can you show me the animation panel and the clip settings  ?

Comment: @Sndpt only if both is going down **in the same frame** which I very very unlikely to happen ..